# How to enable default hightlight for custom ListView items?

Tags: android

There is a custom layout for ListView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I click by item I don't see any highlight; I know that I can do it using selectors, but may be there is the easist way to enable default highlight?

Comment: Post the ListView code too. I _think_ the attribute `android:listSelector=""` may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Remove line:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: Now, I can't. I need to have my items white.

Comment: Then just use an XML stateListDrawable with the default color white.